# sql JOIN cause double rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables that i need to join them

first table i created using this sql query

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_login` varchar(60),
  `user_pass` varchar(255),
  `first_name` varchar(30),
  `last_name` varchar(30),
  `user_status` int(2),
  `user_phone_number` varchar(20),
  `user_email` varchar(100),
  `user_billing_info` text,
  `user_temp_units` int(2),
  `user_flow_units` int(2),
  `user_notes` text
);
```

second table

```
CREATE TABLE `station_meta` (
  `uid` VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
  `nickname` varchar(30),
  `install_date` date,
  `latatude` numeric(10,6),
  `longitude` numeric(10,6),
  `firmware_ver` varchar(10),
  `weir_type` int(2),
  `weir_width` numeric,
  `dist_to_ground` numeric,
  `dist_to_weir` numeric,
  `service_fee` numeric,
  `notes` text
);
```

i got double rows when i use this sql query

```
SELECT * FROM station_meta JOIN users
```

note: uid is something like 9C9Z454Z5CA in case it need to mention it

so there's not any column that is the same in the other table

***UPDATE***

Data sample

[image]

My results

I'm using it in php function in foreach, so i got double results

**Appreciate any help**

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample, your actual result , your expected  result and explain how the 2 tables are joined (which columns in the 2 tables are using for join)

Comment: @scaisEdge ok doing that right now

Comment: @scaisEdge please check, i updated the question, and i joined them using simple the query that i mentionned, table1 JOIN table2 i didn't used any columns for the join, i tried with table1 as z JOIN table2 as x in z.id=x.uid but that didn't make sense because uid is different than id

Comment: Looking to your resul  ..  you have not duplicated  rows  (in the firts rows uid and nicname are duplicated but .not nickname) . you have just a cartesian product between the two table  (do the fact you have not element for join and reduce the result)  ..  so you should add you expected  result

Comment: sorry @scaisEdge i'm really confused, what's your suggestion or solution for that ? what cause that double rows ?

Comment: The rows  are not dupled ..  could be you want for a row of table  station_meta just one rows of the table user also if the are not relation between the two table .. Please confirm o add  the expected result  eg .. the first row for user or the last joind

Comment: Anyway if you want a single row  for station_meta  related  with a single row for user you need  a macthing  join .. you need  a common value between the tow table  .. could be in your schema is missing some columns or a relation

Comment: 'INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html (you have an inner join)

Comment: i have posted  an answer  for some suggestion  ..  hope is useful

Answer (score 0):

seems you miss a relation between the two tables  ..
if you want avoid cartesian product and retrieve just a matching value between the two table you should add  a relation as

```
table user_station_meta (
    `id` bigint PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id bigint
    station_meta_uid VARCHAR(25)
)

once you have inserted the matching values  

uid,        id
9c2748..    1
BC8CD4..    5
```

you can select single matching  result  as

```
select u.*. s.*
from  user_station_meta us
JOIN station_meta s on s.uid = us.uid
JOIN users u on u.id = us.id
```